# is it possible to change the background of an icon downloaded from a webiste.-CSS

Tags: css

I have an image I downloaded from a google search website:

https://www.google.com/search?q=filter+svg+icon&oq=filter.svg&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i30l9.3625j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

I'm trying to remove the white background I see behind the icon
I tried with CSS:

```
display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 82px;
    background: url(filter.jpeg) no-repeat top left transparent;
    background-size: contain;
    /* background-position: 50% 0; */
    /* background-size: cover; */
    /* opacity: 0.2; */
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    color: #fff;
```

nothing works. Is there any way I can remove the white background and make it transparent so that when I upload the image in my app, the white or any background color should not be visible?

[image]

Comment: There's no white background in the SVG, you can check that in the [svgomg](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) the background is transparent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It it not possible to remove background with CSS. It should be done with graphic softwares.

Although I saw the icon in your google link and its SVG! So based on your icon:

### Google

Try saving the icon from google. If the icon has no background google will show a Transparent tiled background like you see
[image: The google save]

### The website

I checked the website was flaticon. which offers `png` for free. But the `svg` was premium. You can download `png` version for free as you see! you can choose your desired size by clicking side button of `png`!

[image: The Flat Icon]

### Fontawsome (Best Way)

I Strongly suggest to use font icons like `font-awsome`! It's free, standard, and cached on most user browsers because most websites use it! I checked it includes [your icon in free version](https://fontawesome.com/search?q=filter&o=r):

[image: Font Awsome]

There is a good [Quick Start](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/get-started) doc if you don't know how to use it.

Comment: I thought so too, but the icon is not saving as svg, its saving either as jpeg or png. even otehr wise its still showing the background as white even when I saved as svg